# Python How to print output from classes and defined objects with treference to text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am having trouble printing output from a text file when using classes and defined objects. Also how can I trouble shoot my code so the information in the text file is being appended correctly. I tried outputing using `print(tmp_sta.append(s))` but it did not work. Thanks

```
STA_FILEPATH = r"setup.txt"
STAT_FILEPATH = r"station.txt"

class low:    
    def __init__(self, n, b, c, l, m):
        self.n = n                    
        self.b = b            
        self.c = c                  
        self.l = l              
        self.m = m             
        self.status = 0                        
        self.tm_init = float("inf")            



class Stage:
    def __init__(self, n, f, t):
        self.n = n                    
        self.f = f      
        self.t = t          
        self.load_list = []            

def setup_ufls_stages():
    sta_file = open(STA_FILEPATH,'r')
    stat_file = open(STAT_FILEPATH,'r')
    tmp_sta = []

    for line in sta_file:
        temp_str = (line.rstrip('\n')).split('\t')
        s = Stage(int(temp_str[0]), float(temp_str[1]), float(temp_str[2]))
        tmp_sta.append(s)

    for line in station_file:
        temp_str = (line.rstrip('\n')).split('\t')
        stage = int(temp_str[0])
        s = low(temp_str[5], int(temp_str[1]), int(temp_str[2]), float(temp_str[3]), int(temp_str[4]))
        tmp_sta[stage - 1].load_list.append(s)

    sta_file.close()
    stat_file.close()
    print(tmp_sta.append(s))

    return tmp_sta
```

Comment: Straight away I can say `print(tmp_sta.append(s))` won't work for troubleshooting because you'll `print` the returned value of `append`; `append` works in-place and returns `None` so you won't get any print out.

Comment: Beyond that, can you be a bit more specific in what isn't working? Are you using `print` here as a debugging method or did you want that to print the result of the `append`?

Comment: I actually want to do both

Comment: I think you're jumping too many steps ahead on this question. From your current code, it's not clear to me what your expected output should look like.

Comment: i have two text files, and let's say if I enter a number, will it output the correct information associated with that line, the 6 variables in the class

Comment: so is there a way to do that. also I want to output both text files to make sure it is reading correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
print(tmp_sta.append(s))
```

You can't combine `print()` and `append()` like this. `list.append` modifies the list but always returns `None` so you need separate commands:

```
tmp_sta.append(s)
print(s)
```

To make your class print useful debugging information, add a `__repr__` method. For example:

```
class low:    
    def __init__(self, n, b, c, l, m):
        ....

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'low({})'.format(
            ', '.join('{}={!r}'.format(k, getattr(self, k))
                for k in ['n', 'b', 'c', 'l', 'm', 'status', 'tm_init'])
        )
```

Comment: i used this method, its not printing